# How do I get gradle incremental native c++ compilation to handle generated headers?

Tags: gradle

I have a header that is generated at build time in a task that I make the compile task depend on, trouble is that the compilation task doesn't recognize when the header is changed in the incremental compilation. So even if the task is run it will not compile the source file.

I would have expected that the generated header should show up as a "Discovered include" and cause the source files to be rebuilt but not so.

Below is the best I have come up with but it does not work.

```
apply plugin: 'cpp'

model {
  binaries {
    all {
      cppCompiler.args "-I$buildDir/gen"
    }
  }
  components {
    test(NativeExecutableSpec) {
      sources {
        cpp {
          source {
            srcDir "."
            include "*.cpp"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

task generateHeader(type: Copy) {
  into "$buildDir/gen"
  from(rootProject.file('template.h')) {
    rename(/template/, 'generated')
    expand([text: 'foo'])
  }
}

tasks.all { task ->
  def match = task.name =~ /^compile.*Cpp$/
  if (match) {
    task.dependsOn generateHeader

    task.inputs.files project.fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/gen").matching {
      include '*.h'
    }
  }
}
```

Sample project: https://github.com/thejk/gradle-incremental-cpp-generated-header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got help on the gradle forum, long story short: create a C(pp)SourceSet with generatedBy tasks.generateHeader and modify generateHeader to export headerDir and sourceDir properties. Link the source set to the real one with lib.

```
sources {
    headers(CppSourceSet) {
      generatedBy tasks.generateHeader
    }
    cpp {
      source {
        srcDir "."
        include "*.cpp"
      }
      lib sources.headers
    }
}

task generateHeader(type: HeaderGenerator) {
  template rootProject.file('template.h')
  headerDir project.file("$buildDir/gen")
}

class HeaderGenerator extends DefaultTask {
  @InputFile
  File template
  @OutputDirectory
  File headerDir
  @OutputDirectory
  @Optional
  File sourceDir

  @TaskAction
  void generate() {
    project.copy {
      into headerDir
      from(template) {
        rename(/template/, 'generated')
        expand([text: 'foo'])
      }
    }
  }
}
```